# Multi-Client REST Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-boot

I have a RESTful Spring Boot web service, that is to be consumed from two different types of clients (Angularjs and Android). I am trying to implement a Spring Oauth2 authentication for an Android client and CSRF tokens for the Angular web client.

Is it possible to implement two of these security implementations side by side and have Spring check if an authentication request matches either of the options? If so, what am I doing wrong with the code below?

```
@Configuration
public class ServerConfiguration {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    protected static class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
            return authenticationManager;
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/login.html", "/", "/oauth/token").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
                .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
        }

        private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
            return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
                @Override
                protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                        HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                        throws ServletException, IOException {
                    CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class
                            .getName());
                    if (csrf != null) {
                        Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                        String token = csrf.getToken();
                        if (cookie == null || token != null
                                && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                            cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                            cookie.setPath("/");
                            response.addCookie(cookie);
                        }
                    }
                    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                }
            };
        }

        private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
            HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
            repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
            return repository;
        }
    }

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "council-alert-oauth";

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    @Order(2)
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends
            ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            // @formatter:off
            resources
                .resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/report/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('write')")
                    .antMatchers("/api/user/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('write')")
                    .antMatchers("/api/employee/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('write')")
                    .antMatchers("/api/citizen/report").access("#oauth2.hasScope('write')");
            // @formatter:on
        }

    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    @Order(2)
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends
            AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        private TokenStore tokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
                throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            endpoints
                .tokenStore(this.tokenStore)
                .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            clients
                .inMemory()
                /*  
                .withClient("angular-client")
                        .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                        .authorities("ADMIN")
                        .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                        .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                        .secret("council-alert-angular-secret")
                        //.redirectUris("http://localhost:8080/")
                        .autoApprove(true)
                    .and()*/
                    .withClient("android-client")
                         .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                         .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                         .authorities("ADMIN")
                         .scopes("read", "write")
                         .secret("council-alert-android-secret")
                    .and()
                    .withClient("android-client")
                        .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                        .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                        .authorities("USER")
                        .scopes("read", "write")
                        .secret("council-alert-android-secret");
            // @formatter:on            
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
            DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
            tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
            tokenServices.setTokenStore(this.tokenStore);
            return tokenServices;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am doing the same.